# Lot of Custom Annotation in Mapkit cause issue

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I am loading over 600 (sometimes are over 1000) annotations in a map kit. I have created a custom Annotation.m. 
The first time that the annotations are loaded the mapkit is fine. If try to refresh (remove all pins send the request on the server, convert the responded json to annotations and add it back to map view) the map shows nothing until I tapped once on the map. Then annotations are appeared on the map. Sometimes it load some of the annotations and if I tap once it show the rest.
Any ideas? I have a lot of code so guide me what to copy here.
Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you should be lazy loading your annotation data from your server. Are you actually displaying 1000 annotations to the user at the same time? I don't know about the behavior when you tap. But I would suggest only loading what needs to be displayed to the user and see if your unexpected behavior resolves.

Comment: Actually the I am sending coordinates to the user and it replies me with POI's arounds me. What do mean laze loading annotation data from server?

Comment: [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). Essentially, only grab what you need to display. As you need to show more annotations, fetch them.